# dataframe from dictionary of dictionary in list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary like that :

```
my_list = [
    {
        'Currency': 'USD',
        'Product': 'a',
        'Quantity': {
            'Apr 2019': 1.0,
            'Jun 2019': 7.0
        }
    },
    {
        'Currency': 'USD',
        'Product': 'b',
        'Quantity': {
            'Jan 2019': 4.0,
            'Feb 2019': 8.0
        }
    }
]
```

And I want a dataframe like that :

```
 Currency Product Quantity  Date
 'USD'      'a'      1      Apr 2019
 'USD'      'a'      7      Jun 2019
 'USD'      'b'      4      Jan 2019
 'USD'      'b'      8      Feb 2019
```

currently I am doing that :

```
for element in my_list :
     currency = element.get('Currency')
     product = element.get('Product')
     dates = list(element.get('Quantity').keys())
     for date in dates:
         quantity = element.get('Quantity')[date]
         row = [currency, product, quantity, date]
         df.loc[df.shape[0]] = row
```

But I imagine there is a better way instead of loop in the list and

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_list)
```

works if there is only one value in quantity (with a little modification with .apply)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df_dict = [{**d, "Quantity": quantity, "Date": date,} for d in my_list for date, quantity in d['Quantity'].items()]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
```

**output**:

```
>>> df

Currency    Product Quantity    Date
0   USD         a       1.0         Apr 2019
1   USD         a       7.0         Jun 2019
2   USD         b       4.0         Jan 2019
3   USD         b       8.0         Feb 2019
```

**Explanation**:

By using a double-nested loop, you enumerate your list by the number of quantity/date pairs -which is what you want. Then you unpack the dictionary on the first level (using `**d`). This sets the correct `Currency` and `Product` values but leaves us with the "bad" `Quantity` value. This is overwritten in the next step of the dictionary comprehension. And finally, `Date` is set. From there, it's simply pandas reading each dictionary as a row.

Comment: ok thnaks, it works for this example
my data is quite different, there is in reality two dict in the dict (one with quantity and date, and the same with value and date (the date is the same))
I can adapt your solution (especially the part with for date, quantity in d['Quantity'].items()) or not?

Comment: ok I have process with the same than above :
"Value": d.get('Value')[date] 
in your dictionary

Comment: @kilag hmmm, I'm not quite picturing what you're describing. Can you send me an example dictionary? Either way, my guess is that my solution shouldn't be used if there are many more things to unpack. It will become a very messy solution once you have to unpack 3 or more nested dictionaries.

Comment: My object is like that :
my_list = [
    {
        'Currency': 'USD',
        'Product': 'a',
        'Quantity': {
            'Apr 2019': 1.0,
            'Jun 2019': 7.0
        },
    'Value': {
            'Apr 2019': 10.4,
            'Jun 2019': 72.1
        }
    },
    {
        'Currency': 'USD',
        'Product': 'b',
        'Quantity': {
            'Jan 2019': 4.0,
            'Feb 2019': 8.0
        },
       'Value': {
            'Jan 2019': 1.45,
            'Feb 2019': 2.98
        }
    }
]

So by adding  "Value": d.get('Value')[date] it works

Answer (score 1):

Use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df=json_normalize(my_list,'Quantity',['Currency','Product'])
Quantity=[]
for d in my_list:
    for month in  d['Quantity']:
        Quantity.append(d['Quantity'][month])
df['Quantity']=Quantity
df=df.rename(columns={0:'Date'}).reindex(columns=['Currency','Product','Quantity','Date'])
print(df)


  Currency Product  Quantity      Date
0      USD       a       1.0  Apr 2019
1      USD       a       7.0  Jun 2019
2      USD       b       4.0  Jan 2019
3      USD       b       8.0  Feb 2019
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use double loop for processing your data.

The following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            'Currency': item.get('Currency'),
            'Product': item.get('Product'),
            'Date': quant_key,
            'Quantity': quant_val,
        } for item in my_list for quant_key, quant_val in item['Quantity'].items()
    ]
)
print(df)
```

returns this output:

```
  Currency Product      Date  Quantity
0      USD       a  Apr 2019       1.0
1      USD       a  Jun 2019       7.0
2      USD       b  Jan 2019       4.0
3      USD       b  Feb 2019       8.0
```

Comment: thanks, I will keep this one with a little modification, I add 
'Value': item.get('Value')[quant_key]
in the loop to add a value from an other dict